# Set arithmetic in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Can we perform set arithmetic in SymPy?

I could only find how to do some very specific set arithmetics using `imageset`.

For example I could get the set of integers plus half but when trying to use a lambda with more than one variable it gives a `ValueError('Incompatible signature')` and though I couldn't find the exact reason I assume it is since it only supports one parameter for the lambda in imageset:

```
>>> print(imageset(lambda x: x + 1/2, S.Integers))
ImageSet(Lambda(x, x + 1/2), Integers)
>>> print(imageset(lambda x,y: x + y, S.Integers*S.Rationals))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/66.426491309333028408/sympy/sympy/sets/sets.py", line 2058, in imageset
    r = ImageSet(f, set)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~sympy-live-hrd/66.426491309333028408/sympy/sympy/sets/fancysets.py", line 317, in __new__
    raise ValueError('Incompatible signature')
ValueError: Incompatible signature
```

Of course, summing the rationals and the integers doesn't give an interesting result, but for arbitrary sets it could be used to sum sets and similarily could be used to subtract or multiply sets (element wise).

Is there any other way to perform set addition/subtraction/multiplication using `imageset` or maybe there is something like `set_add(S,T)`?

Comment: You can use `imageset(lambda x, y: x + y, Integers, Rationals)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My foresight into how things *should* be is limited with the sets module, but the way it works now is that you must send the sets for each arg of the lambda separately:

```
>>> imageset(lambda x,y: x+y, Integers,Integers)
ImageSet(Lambda((x, y), x + y), Integers, Integers)
```

see also: SetExpr